# Mongoose populated is not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

Mongoose `populated` documentation:

```
Model.findOne().populate('author').exec(function (err, doc) {
    console.log(doc.author.name)         // Dr.Seuss
    console.log(doc.populated('author')) // '5144cf8050f071d979c118a7'
})
```

My code:

```
Job.find({operator: user.operator, status: {$nin: ['assigned', 'unassigned', 'completed']}})
        .populate('version', 'results.routes')
        .exec(function(err, jobs)
        {
            console.log(jobs.populated('version'))
            ...
```

I have been getting this error when the code runs:
`TypeError: jobs.populated is not a function`

Why am I getting this error? What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Posting Job model:

```
var JobSchema = new Schema(
    {
        created: Date,
        received: Date,
        due_date: Date,
        freight: Number,
        creator: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        operator: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Operator' },
        routing: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Routing' },
        version: { 
            type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Version',
            validate: [validateStarredVersion, 'You must star this route before monitoring it.']
        },
        ...
```

The version model:

```
var VersionSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
    routing: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Routing' },
    name: String,
    number: Number,
    date: Date,
    tags: [String],
    results:
    {
        routes:
        [ resultSchema ],
    ...
```

resultsSchema:

```
var resultSchema = new Schema(
{
    name: String,
    vehicle: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    distance: Number,
    weight: Number,
    volume: Number,
    capacity_weight: Number,
    capacity_volume: Number,
    occupancy_weight: Number,
    occupancy_volume: Number,
    job: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Job' },
    operator: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    delivery_order:
    [
        {
            delivery: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
            depot: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
            arrival_time: Date
        }
    ],
    directions: [ directionSchema ]
});
```

I have not edited with the entired object because it's too large. I put only the related information.

Comment: Show us your _Job_ model.

Comment: @TGrif question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation uses `findOne()`, while your code uses `find()`. This means the variable `jobs` isn't a mongoose document, but an array of mongoose documents. The native `Array` doesn't have a method `.populated()`

Comment: I've noticed that the docs are using `findOne` but someone tells me that `populated` works in `find` too. When I use `job.populated('version')` inside a `forEach` works fine. But my problem now is that I cannot use it when `populate` returns undefined. My server crashes before fall in forEach > populated > handling.

Comment: Are you looking for confirmation that ALL of them are populated, or just that it succeeded? You could do an existence check: `if (jobs && jobs[0] && jobs[0].populated("version")) {}`